# ansible-playbook: Variable that holds the value of "-u"?

Tags: ansible

Is there an Ansible variable that holds the value of the "-u" cli parameter?

For example:

```
ansible-playbook some-things.yml -u some-user
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

`ansible_user` seems to record the name of the user that the playbook was being executed as; I don't need that. I need the explicitly specified username on the cli.

Comment: If you want to execute playbook actions with some user you can add the variable `remote_user: YOURUSER` to your playbook (or add in the command line as an extravar). You can change it also in ansible.cfg, although if you change it there, it will be applied to all your playbooks)

Comment: @AlvaroNiño No, I need the playbook to know the username being used to run the playbook and checks it against an external information source. I do NOT want to specify what the username will be; rather, each DevOps engineer will use _their_ own respective username.

Comment: Why don't engineers add these varibales in their command line? as `ansible-playbook YOURPLAY.yml --extra-vars "remoteuser=Engineer"`, also they can add such variables as `--private-key` or `--ask-pass`

Comment: @AlvaroNiño Yes, they *have* been adding parameters, in the form of `-u`. Adding more parameters will result in more chances of someone doing things the wrong way. Rather than forcing people to use a custom variable to do things `-u` have been doing, why not read the `-u` parameter directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such variable.

If you want to fetch CLI arguments from inside the playbook you will have to write some plugin. You can get some inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40874476/2795592) where fetching `--tags` is shown.

The reason you get local user name from `ansible_user` is because (I guess) you run the task in a context of localhost, where connection is `local`, hence user name is local. But `-u` switch stands for remote user. You can trick Ansible to think you want to execute task remotely and get remote user name from `ansible_user` magic variable. Like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        rem_usr: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      delegate_to: some_fake_host_name
    - debug:
        msg: "local={{ ansible_user }}, remote={{ rem_usr }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I finaly wrote my own lookup script to latch into the `cli` object and parse the options (the `cli.options` object is apparently a `Namespace` object returned by `argparse()`).